# What spells can not be found as loot in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Yes, I'm aware that spell books are rare loot and if you want them all, it is more useful to buy them. But I don't want to - it is a roleplaying thing. I'm not a mage anyway and don't have the maciga for most of the spells, I want them all because I'm a hopeless idealist. And I don't mind that it will take time, Skyrim is still one of my favorite games and exploring and clearing new dungeons is what's fun, so having the possibilyty of finding a new spell adds to that.
Therefore I do not want to buy even one spell that can be obtained otherwise. Which are the spells that never drop, even inside Black Books, and can only be obtained by buying them?

Answer (score 2):

According to the uesp wiki (http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spells),

> Nearly all spell tomes can also be found randomly as loot. The only spell tomes that can not be found randomly are quest-specific spell tomes (those that can not be purchased), tomes added by Dawnguard or Dragonborn, and master-level tomes. The appearance of random tomes is dependent upon your character's overall level (but is not related to your skill in the magic school, unlike tome purchases)

Comment: So does that mean that in Dragonborn dungeons, spell books added by Dragonborn do not drop? Also, (though my level is way high, over 70) I have have one master level spell drop inside a Black Book - I have the Flame Thrall spell, and my destruction is only 80, and was below that when I got it.

Comment: That is interesting, especially about the master level spell. Looks like the wiki is off on this one.

Comment: Actually going through the list, the wiki does mention this further down (Flame Thrall: "Found in Apocrypha - The Sallow Regent"), but this seems to be the only exception to the rule